# How can I keep calendar events in Apple Calendar when my work Outlook account is deleted?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, calendar

When I retire shortly, my work Exchange Outlook account will be deleted. I use Apple Mail to display all emails and Apple Calendar to display all calendar events. It's easy to archive email in Mail. I want to keep Outlook calendar events too, so I can look back and see what was happening at work in the future.

I realise that I can set each Apple Calendar Exchange Outlook event to my Apple account, but there are thousands of events over many, many years . . . So I wondered if there was an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Depends where your Outlook email is, if it's local on a PC as a single .pst file you need to take that and any other local file Outlook these days uses. If it's on Outlook.com, then there is no problem, it's all there. If you email is local, you could as your system admin or Microsoft if you can upload it to and Outlook.com email account. Anyway this is a question for your system admin for sure and they should be able to solve it, it's literally their job description.

Answer (score 0):

### Copy and Paste your calendar folder to your (new) *outlook.com* account.

Preserving calendar events at **outlook.com** account may give you the best results because it is also Outlook Exchange account so this way you can achieve minimal loss of information.

1. Create your free account at [outlook.com](https://outlook.com).
2. Connect the account into your desktop client so you can see both work and **outlook.com** accounts there.
3. Switch your work calendar to list view so you can see hundreds of your events in a list.
4. Select all calendar items in the list (typically using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>) and copy them to clipboard.
5. Switch your **outlook.com** calendar to list view so you can have good overview over next operation.
6. Paste your clipboard and wait until copying is finished.
7. Check information on total count of items in folder to verify that that all items are now copied.
8. (optional) Disconnect your **outlook.com** account from the application.
9. Connect your personal device to your **outlook.com** account and check the visibility there.

   - The above actions 1~8 can be conveniently done in Microsoft Outlook desktop application.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for this! As it turns out, I bought an app on the Mac App store called OLM File Convertor. In Outlook, I selected Export which created a .olm file. I opened this file in OLM File Convertor which then converted all the Outlook Calendar items into a .ics file which in Apple Calendar app, I was then able to import. Simple and easy.